# Trouble returning correct results when comparing 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables like this:

products

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>description</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>book</td>
        <td>book desc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>tea</td>
        <td>tea desc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>glasses</td>
        <td>glasses desc</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

product_attributes

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>product_id</th>
        <th>attribute_id</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>7</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I also have two variables (strings), `$pid` and `$search_ids`

`$pid` contains product ids, and has a value of `2,3,1`
`$search_ids` contains attribute ids, and has a value of `7,8`

I want to return `name` from `products` table, IF in `product_attributes` table both `product_id` and `attribute_id` in one row contain a value from `$pid` and `$search_ids`.

So in the case of tables specified above, I expect to get only `TEA` returned, because only its id matches both ids of `$search_ids` in the `product_attributes` table.

I tried the following but this returns all products I have four times for some reason:

```
$q = "SELECT p.name FROM products AS p, product_attributes AS pa WHERE p.id IN ($pid) AND pa.product_id IN ($pid) AND pa.attribute_id IN ($search_ids)";
```

Comment: Why are you showing _HTML_ tables, when this question is about SQL?

Comment: I am just showing the structure of the tables in the database. I did not put select and html table tags inside the question, it was edited by someone.

Comment: Don't downvote before asking, damn.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22406395/revisions makes that hard to believe, it shows the HTML table code in the original version already.

Comment: Who's shaking your cage boy? I  said I did not put the HTML-TABLE and SELECT TAGS for the questions (like i have php and mysql). The table structure IS my own and I just said why I put it so. Lay off.

Comment: Well, that’s exactly what I was talking about initially – wtf are you showing us _HTML code_ to describe the structure of your _database_ tables? That makes little sense, and is harder to read as if you had just posted the structure as some kind of “ASCII art” and marked as code.

Comment: OK you got half a point there, but on the other hand I thought someone might just copy/paste it in an html page to quickly and easily see the table structure.

Answer (score 0):

try this change

```
SELECT  p.name 
FROM products AS p, product_attributes AS pa 
WHERE p.id = pa.product_id  <---!!!
AND p.id IN ($pid) AND pa.attribute_id IN ($search_ids)
```

you need  to specify the join.

Comment: With this I get all products names returned once (instead of 4 times as I had before), and after that I get `tea` returned twice, instead of once. Guess that's half way there :D

Comment: It doesn't unfortunately.